# Visual Studio 2013 RC & Visual Studio Tools for Office - TF400422 Error when using Excel

Tags: excel, vsto, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2013 RC running on Windows 8 Pro 64 bit. Also installed is Office 2013 64 bit. The team server is TFS2012.

When I want to send my queries or items to Excel, Visual Studio responds with:

`Microsoft Visual Studio
Team Foundation Error
TF400422: Failed to open in Microsoft Excel: Error loading type library/Dll.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))`

I have installed the latest Visual Studio Tools for Office. I also tried to manually register the `TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll` assembly but that also failed with errors.

Queries or items sent to Outlook works perfectly...

Is this a current short-coming of VS2013RC and/or VSTO, or is there a solution to get it working?

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem, goggled it but with no success.

Problem is that everything worked till today. So it isn't compatibility 64bit vs 32bit.

Also, Outlook queries are working fine.

I have bypassed problem by opening query from excel, the team tab.

Comment: Good workaround, later versions of Office & VS works perfectly together. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

TFS2012 and 2013 do not work with the 64-bit version of Microsoft Office